# SQL query to return the most popular vote for color

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

We are creating a voting system with the following tables:

```
Color: id, name
Panel: id, name
Votes: id, color_id, panel_id
```

We are struggling with defining the correct query for getting the most voted color per panel.

Currently we are looping through all the panels (in Ruby) and perform the following SQL query:

```
select colors.name, count(colors.name) as count 
from votes 
join colors on colors.id = votes.renderable_id 
where panel_id = X 
group by colors.name 
order by count desc 
limit 1;
```

This returns the following information:

```
name | count 
-----+-------
red  |    34
```

We would like to optimise, and include the panels in the query by grouping on the panel_id, so that we do not need to loop over all panels. Our first try was this:

```
select votes.panel_id, colors.name, count(colors.name) as count 
from votes 
join colors on colors.id = votes.renderable_id 
group by votes.panel_id, colors.name;
```

returning

```
panel_id | name | count 
---------+------+-------
       8 | blue |    52
       5 | blue |    14
       8 | red  |    34
```

and we would like to also remove the duplication of the panel_id, and select the max(count). We can't get this working?

Is there an SQL expert who can help us implement this into one single SQL query? We already thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select panel_id, max(count) as count
from ( 
     select votes.panel_id, colors.name, count(colors.name) as count 
     from votes 
     join colors on colors.id = votes.renderable_id 
     group by votes.panel_id, colors.name
     ) src
group by panel_id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need panel and color names, you can use only one table for this (which is also the fastest solution):

```
SELECT panel_id, color_id, MAX(votes) FROM (
  SELECT panel_id, color_id, COUNT(id) AS votes 
  FROM votes
  GROUP BY panel_id, color_id;
) t1
```

If you need the names, then it is quite similar:

```
SELECT panel_id, panel_name, color_id, color_name, MAX(votes) FROM (
  SELECT panel_id, panel.name AS panel_name, color_id, color.name AS color_name, COUNT(id) AS votes 
  FROM votes
  LEFT JOIN panel ON panel.id = votes.panel_id
  LEFT JOIN color ON color.id = votes.color_id
  GROUP BY panel_id, color_id;
) t1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical case for windowing functions which MySQL doesn't support. So we use group_concat instead to list all colors per panel ordered by votes and cut out the first.

```
select best_votes.panel_id, colors.name, best_votes.maxcnt
from
(
  select 
    panel_id, 
    max(cnt) as maxcnt,
    substring_index(concat(group_concat(color_id order by cnt desc separator ','), ','), ',', 1) as maxcolor
  from
  (
    select panel_id, color_id, count(*) as cnt
    from votes
    group by panel_id, color_id
  )
  group by panel_id
) best_votes
join colors on colors.id = best_votes.maxcolor;
```